# Adding corresponding elements from two arrays into new array using csh shell?

Tags: scripting, csh

I want to use a csh script to merge corresponding elements of two arrays into another array. My script gives error as:-

> arrayfinal[1]: No match. the results is 0 0 0 0 0

my script is

```
#!/bin/csh
set array1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
set array2 = {1,4,9,16,25}
#set arrayfinal={`$array1[1]+$array2[1]`}
@ count=$#array1
@ index =1
set arrayfinal = {0,0,0,0,0}
while ($index <= $count)

arrayfinal[$index] =array1[$index]+array2[$index]
@ index++


echo "the results is $arrayfinal"
exit 0
```

thanks.

Comment: Should be `@ arrayfinal[$index] = $array1[$index] + $array2[$index]`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `end` to delimit the `while` loop, missing the `@` for one of the arithmetic expressions and have a few issues with your `@` syntax:

```
#!/bin/csh
set array1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
set array2 = {1,4,9,16,25}
@ count = $#array1
@ index =1
set arrayfinal = {0,0,0,0,0}
while ($index <= $count)
  @ arrayfinal[$index] = $array1[$index] + $array2[$index]
  @ index++
end

echo "the results is $arrayfinal"
exit 0
```